# Looking for a Python Web navigation library

Tags: python, scripting, automation, beautifulsoup

I want to automate tasks done through the web with a python script. Right now, I have tried Beautiful Soup and I am able to visit pages and retrieve data. However, I am more interested in mimicking button clicks and checkbox clicks from code and navigating to new pages.

Figure 1 is the initial url I want to visit. Afterwards, I want to be able to automate the clicking of all the "Apply Now" Buttons. (They share the same HTML class if that helps). 
[image: Figure 1 - url]

After clicking an "Apply Now" Button I am redirected to Figure 2. Here I want to 
mimic the click of the two "Start" links and click "Submit Scholarship Application" through the code. 
[image: Figure 2]

I just want to be pointed in the right direction with proper libraries to use and some method calls that will help.

Please and Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the powerful Python library Selenium.  I use it all the time! Here's some example code to get you started once you install it - of course, modify it to apply to the HTML you're actually working with!

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url = 'urlyouwanttogoto.com'
driver.get(url)
boxesyouwanttocheck = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('whatevertheclassnameis')
for i in boxesyouwanttocheck:
    i.click()
```

This will click the boxes for you (after, of course, you change it to reflect the html that's actually there :))

Comment: Thank You! The code is really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

> I want to mimic the click of the two "Start" links and click "Submit Scholarship Application" through the code.

This all sounds as you need to *automate a browser* and simulate real-user interactions. There is a specific library that allows you to fire up a real browser, make clicks, send keys to specific elements - [`selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/).

> Right now, I have tried Beautiful Soup

Note that `BeautifulSoup` is just an *HTML Parser* - it is not a browser.

Comment: Thanks a lot! this helps